# Can I add multiple modules to nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I am new to NodeJS. What I wanted to know is, can I like call 2 **JS** files using **NodeJS & ExpressJS**. Basically I want to have 2 seperate files so I can work on one and my partner can work on another one. So I want **Server.js** to call one file which contains some part of my **REST API** and other one contains rest of the function.

```
|--NodeModules[etc..]
|--Server.js
|--Rest/
|  |--RestAPI1.js
|  |--RestAPI2.js
```

It will be really helpful in the development of my project, if this is possible.

Comment: Are you using any framework or library to build the api? You can include the logic for handling different routes in separate files

Comment: I am using ExpressJS. the tutorial i am following had everything in one file.
like

`var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.json({ 'status': status });
});
app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(8080);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define routes in different files like this:

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router1 = require("./routers/router1");
var app = express();
.....

app.use("/user", router1);
```

**Router1.js**

```
var router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
...
});

module.exports = router;
```